# Best solution for Java web based forms connected to Oracle plus JNI?

Tags: oracle, forms, jsf

My company is currently undergoing efforts to migrate from Informix to Oracle 10g. We don't want to use any form of oracle forms but instead want to create Java web based forms that interact with the Oracle db (these will replace our Informix forms). Some of the forms also need to implement some JNI to our underlying C code libraries.

What's the best way to tackle this - ie, using JSF?

Opinions welcome!
Karen

Answer (score 0):

There really is no "Best Way".. look at the tools available and assess for yourself.

Without knowing the scope of your project, I'd personally look at something like [Grails](http://www.grails.org/)

Comment: I was looking for opinions but I'm curious why you would point to Grails? I don't think it's something we'd be interested in if there's too much of a learning curve involved as our project is already large in scope. The forms themselves aren't the largest part of the project, just overall we have our hands full enough. We'll have approximately 300 forms to create where probably 60-70% of those are quite basic and just interface an Oracle table. The other 30-40% will require more robust logic and some JNI.

Comment: Grails just looks interesting to me.

If 60-70% of it is forms, I'd actually look at APEX, enough though you've said you don't want a Oracle forms solution, its quite nice and great for "CRUD" applications.

Answer (score 0):

@KNewton Right now, my company is undergoing on a similar project. 
Which java framework did you use to re-write your oracle forms application?